# Android M - Is there any way to know whether a user has chosen to never see the grant permissions dialog ever again?

Tags: android, android-permissions

If an app calls [ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String%5B%5D,int)), the OS displays a dialog with "Deny" and "Permit" buttons. There is also a "Never show this again" tick box.

There's no way that I can see for the app to know whether the user has ticked this box. Within [onRequestPermissionsResult(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,java.lang.String%5B%5D,int%5B%5D)), the `grantResults` parameter is [PERMISSION_DENIED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#PERMISSION_DENIED) if the user clicks "Deny" and also if the user ticks the tick box before clicking "Deny".

Is there any way an app can find out whether the user doesn't want to see that dialog again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String)) - it will return `false` in a few cases:

- You've never asked for the permission before
- The user has checked the 'never again' checkbox
- The permission has been disabled by policy (say, in a work situation)

By combining this with a shared preference to store if you've ever asked for permission, you can effectively determine if they'll actually see the dialog when you call [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String%5B%5D,int)).

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this answer and wanting a more in depth explanation of how to combine the [shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String)) method with a value in shared preferences, see my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73826849/1071320).

Answer (score 1):

As [Ian Lake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) has hinted ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33224639/1071320)), we can save a "user has requested permission twice" value in persistent storage (e.g. shared preferences) to help us determine when a call into [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String%5B%5D,int)) will be ignored by the operating system.

In my opinion, the point at which we should save this boolean value in persistent storage is when the user taps the positive button in our custom "request permission rationale" popup right before we make our second call to [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String%5B%5D,int)).

Subsequently, if [shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String)) returns `false` and our "user has requested permission twice" value is `true`, then we should direct the user to the Settings app instead of making a third call to the [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String%5B%5D,int)) method.

For a concrete example of the above, see [this small app](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-runtime-permission-experiments/tree/master/app2) which I have put together to demonstrate this workaround exactly.

All of the above said, it's a huge shame that the Android APIs do not allow us to ask a very simple question of the operating system: "Has the user denied the permission permanently?"

Comment: So, what happens when the user goes to the settings and selects "Ask every time"? Unfortunately, shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() is still false after that.

Comment: Good question. When the user selects "Ask every time?" in the app's settings after having previously acknowledged the custom "request permission rationale" popup, the app will then be in a state where `checkSelfPermission()` returns `PERMISSION_DENIED`, `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` returns `false` and our "user has requested permission twice" value is `true`. In this state, the app will direct the user to the Settings app the next time it needs the permission even though it is entitled to request the permission from the user directly. It's not a perfect solution for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the cases which may occur and the values which you will receive from the [checkSelfPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)) (**flag**) and [shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String)) (**shouldShow**) method in each case:

| # | Case | flag | shouldShow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | App has never asked for the permission | -1 | false |
| 2 | User has allowed the permission | 0 | false |
| 3 | User has denied the permission without ticking the "Don't show again" checkbox | -1 | true |
| 4 | User has denied the permission whilst ticking the "Don't show again" checkbox | -1 | false |
| 5 | User has switched the permission to deny in settings | -1 | true |

As you can see, there is no difference between the 1st case and the 4th case. That's why you need to save the information about previous permission requests (i.e. it's the first request of permission or not). I save this info in app preferences.